# jQuery slideshow with transitions between images and a Flash animation

Tags: jquery, flash, slideshow, transition

Creating a jQuery slideshow comprised of several images with transitions is easy.  But I'm trying to have a Flash animation (SWF) stand in for one of the items in the slide show.  In other words, I'd like to see transitions between the following:

1. Image
2. Flash animation
3. Another image

We've tried several of the jQuery slideshow plug-ins, but the Flash animation doesn't play well -- for example, if we use a simple dissolve transition, the Flash never disappears.

How can this be done, if at all?  We would prefer not to use a Flash-only slide show.

Comment: Hide the movie just before the transition?

Comment: In the case of a dissolve, this would creating a jarring effect.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This is going to be a tough one to solve.

Comment: Indeed!  This is why I've come here. :-)

Comment: try `wmode="transprent"` in flash `<param`

Comment: This works well in IE9, but not so well in Chrome or slightly older version of Firefox.  But thank you for pointing this out; it is close.  This may not be possible without very recent browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small demo with three images and two animations using jQuery Fading effect.

May be this will be useful.

I couldn't find any public URL to show this.

So, I used dropbox.

Please download the files from the following URL.

http://db.tt/q8VPb03U

As I did many assumptions, this may change from required specs. But if there are any issues, I will try to update it.

I checked this in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox and the animation is smooth.

Thanks,
Sasidhar.

EDIT :
The attached file is a ZIP file with html, css, js, images, swf and fla files.